# AG Grid React icons not showing properly after upgrade

Tags: webpack, ag-grid-react

We recently upgraded from ag grid 20.1.0 to 23.0.2. We use webpack to bundle our code and since the upgrade when we build our code in "production" mode the icons do not appear correctly (see below).

[image]

If we run the build locally in "development" mode we have no issues. In reading some of the change logs it looks like ag grid went from svg icons to webfonts and looks like icons are now embedded in the css....at least that is my understanding. Obviously, this has something to do with the way we have webpack configured but for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Below is our webpack.config.js. We are using Sencha Extreact toolset but that hasn't been an issue so far.

```
require('dotenv').config()
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtWebpackPlugin = require('@sencha/ext-webpack-plugin');
const portfinder = require('portfinder');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (env) {
  function get(it, val) {if(env == undefined) {return val} else if(env[it] == undefined) {return val} else {return env[it]}}

  var profile     = get('profile',     '')
  var environment = get('environment', 'development')
  var treeshake   = get('treeshake',   'no')
  var browser     = get('browser',     'yes')
  var watch       = get('watch',       'yes')
  var verbose     = get('verbose',     'no')
  var useConfig   = get('useConfig',  'default')

  const isProd = environment === 'production'
  const outputFolder = 'build'
  portfinder.basePort = (env && env.port) || 8080

  return portfinder.getPortPromise().then(port => {
    const plugins = [
      new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
        NODE_ENV: environment, // use 'development' unless process.env.NODE_ENV is defined
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: "index.html",hash: true,inject: "body"}),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: "../silent_renew/silent_renew.html", filename: "silent_renew.html", inject: 'body'}),
      new ExtWebpackPlugin({
        framework: 'react',
        toolkit: 'modern',
        theme: 'gt-theme',
        emit: 'yes',
        script: '',
        port: port,
        packages: [
          'treegrid',
          'd3'
        ],
        profile: profile, 
        environment: environment,
        treeshake: treeshake,
        browser: browser,
        watch: watch,
        verbose: verbose
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'web.config' },
        { from: './_assets/icons/inv.png', to: 'resources/images' },
      ])
    ]
    return {
      mode: environment,
      devtool: (environment === 'development') ? 'inline-source-map' : false,
      context: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
      entry: {
          app: './index.js',
          silentRenew: "../silent_renew/index.js"
      },
      output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, outputFolder),
        filename: "[name].js"
      },
      plugins: plugins,
      module: {
        rules: [
          { test: /\.(js)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ['babel-loader'] },
          { test: /\.(html)$/,use: { loader: 'html-loader' } },
          {
            test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'style-loader'
              },
              {
                loader: 'css-loader'
              },
              {
                loader: 'sass-loader'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    name: './assets/fonts/[name].[ext]',
                    limit: 100000,
                }
            }]
          },
          {
              test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
              loader: 'url-loader',
              options: {
                  name: './assets/icons/[name].[ext]',
                  limit: 100000,
              }
          }
        ]
      },
      externals: {
        'Config': (useConfig === 'default' ? JSON.stringify(require('./config.json')) 
                                          : JSON.stringify(require('./config.localapi.json')))
      },
      performance: { hints: false },
      stats: 'none',
      optimization: { noEmitOnErrors: true },
      node: { fs: 'empty' },
      devServer: {
        contentBase: outputFolder,
        hot: !isProd,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: port,
        disableHostCheck: false,
        compress: isProd,
        inline:!isProd,
        stats: 'none'
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Update:

Some additional information, in 20.1.0 we were using the following import statement for importing the css:

```
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css';
```

with 23.0.2 we are now importing as follows:

```
import '@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css';
```

I've tried resolving the config:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@ag-grid-community/core": path.resolve('./node_modules/@ag-grid-community/core'),
            react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
      },
```

but that didn't appear to do any good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after countless hours trying to figure out the issue it came down to a simple fix. all I had to do was add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in my index.html `<head>` and like that all the icons appear as expected.